# form_validate work with ff, not with chrome using jQuery trigger click

Tags: forms

I have create a form with form_validate and form_submit functions.

Using Firefox, everything is OK so the problem is not about an error in functions names.

Using Chrome, when I click on submit the page is just reloaded. I have added to my code drupal_debug to track the process into validate function and submit function. System not going into these functions.

I have no ideas about how form_validate function could be linked with choice of browser.

UPDATE : I have found more details about the cause of the problem :

To submit the form, user not click on the submit button directly. He have to click on an other button which launch js function.

At the end of the js function, I use jQuery( "#edit-continue" ).trigger( 'click' ) to simulate click on the real submit button.

I have tried to click directly on the real submit button and it is working but with trigger I see the ajax GIF of drupal but there is no passage to my form_validate function.

So, I really need to know how drupal can make the difference between a real click and an emulated one. And the most important how can I do to fix or skirt this problem.

Comment: That seems extraordinarily unlikely - does it validate if you try it in a third browser, or in Chrome on a different machine? I would say the problem is almost certainly down to your Chrome configuration. Form validation being server-side, the browser can't affect it, unless something's messing with the submission before it gets sent to the server

Comment: clear your cache and try.

Comment: The same problem with IE.
"something's messing with the submission" : but this is the role of form_validate to tell this, it must be ridiculous to check fields before validation. And no one of form fields is required. Is it possible the problem is about jQuery ?

Comment: I have clear the cache, no effect

Comment: @user20761 I mean that your _browser_ or _client-side_ logic is messing with the submission. Unless you have some custom logic in the backend to ignore form submissions. Without seeing the code for every custom or contrib module installed on your site it's impossible to comment. Suffice to say this is non-standard behaviour so it has to be related to a configuration problem with your site/browser/server. I'm afraid I don't follow you about needing to "check fields before validation", that doesn't really make sense in this context

Comment: I have progressed into my search of the bug. The problem is the submit button is hidden. using JS and Jquery selector, I detect click on an other button, do some process and complete some hidden fields and finally trigger click on the real submit button. The problem is that chrome not seems to like trigger.

Comment: If I manually click on submit, it work ( form_validate ). If I use jQuery( "#edit-continue" ).trigger( 'click' ) the page is just reloaded. Why ?

Comment: I have tried to replace jQuery( "#edit-continue" ).trigger( 'click' ) with jQuery( "#form_id" ).submit() but the problem is the same.