# difference between real click and jQuery click

Tags: javascript, forms

I create a new subject which is the next of [this one](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/96088/form-validate-work-with-ff-not-with-chrome).

I have a form on drupal.

There is a function to create it : commerce_checkout_account_pane_checkout_form

There is a function to validate it : commerce_checkout_account_pane_checkout_form_validate

There is a function to submit it : commerce_checkout_account_pane_checkout_form_submit

Everything work with Firefox, but not with Chrome or IE.

If I do a real click on the submit button, I go to the validate function.
If I use jQuery to trigger click on the submit button, I can see ajax gif but my page is reloaded and there was no passage into validate function ( I use drupal_debug to log passage ).

How it is possible there is a difference, in two case there is a click on the submit button ?

All day on this problem, I really need to fix it quickly.

Comment: Hi, I don't see any difference between this and your previous question - if you have more details to add to that, please edit them into the original question rather than asking again. Please bear in mind that questions about pure jQuery/javascript are off-topic here, so if that's the cause of your problem you're likely to get a quicker response on Stack Overflow. Thanks

Comment: Hi @clive, no my question is not pure jQuery/javascript. The problem is linked to drupal working. It's true that the problem is the same but now that I have found the cause with more precision I have more chances to get the solution with a more explicit subject.

Comment: OK, my bad - it's still the same question though, you've just got some more information for it. If your original question has been rendered _incorrect_ by this new information, editing that one into shape is still the right thing to do. When you make the edits it'll rise to the top of the front page again, so don't worry about it not getting any visibility

Comment: ok, so I will update my first question with this new details. thank you for your help and your advices.